# how can I save the whole plist data coming from server (without formatting) to another plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

```
[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:self.responseData 
                                 mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves                                                 
                                           format:&format 
                                 errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```

When the server is online, it sends the responseData. Now I want to save this data(obtained through the responseData in the code) directly to another plist in my app, so that I can retrieve the data later(when the server is offline) in the same format(without changing) and use it/pass it  in the same way as it is being passed when my server is online. I am doing this so that the user of the app does not come to know whether the server is online/offline and still is able to give updates/feedback to the responseData (as he/she would give when the server is online).
 ***I don't want to break the responseData and save it, rather directly save it the way it is coming from the server.***

Please let me know if more explanation is required.And thanks for all the answers that you would be giving :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change anything I believe you should just download the plist as a file and not as data.

To save the file on the phone you should use `NSFileManager`, you can read about it here:[NSFileManager reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) + [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

You must pay attention to the place you save the plist according to apple "new" rules of data storage, you can read about it here:
[Were you should save your files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Good luck

Comment: just one this : could you also clarify whether on retrieving the plist from this file(when in offline mode), the data will remain in the same format as it was saved i.e. in the same sequence? and also if at all I don't download the plist as a file...but just as a plist then, will the structure of the data be disturbed when being retrieved later..??

Comment: If I understand what you are saying then yes, there is no reason that your plist will change. this is simply a text file with a defined structure that make this a plist. on xcode right click on the plist and choose to view the file as text and not as table and you will see that this is a simple text file.